# Create a list of distance matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

Using the Cshapes package in R, I want to create a list of matrices that measure for each year whether two countries are neigbors or not.

```
install.packages("cshapes")
```

Running the code for one year (here 1990) works fine:

`wmat <- distmatrix(as.Date("1990-1-1"), type="mindist", tolerance=0.5, useGW=FALSE)`

This gives a matrix with the following structure:

```
        A   B   C   D
1   A   0   0   210 0
2   B   0   0   637 305
3   C   210 637 0   73
4   D   0   305 73  0
```

In a next step, I set all combinations with 0 distance between two countries to 1, all other combinations to 0, and the diagonal to 0 again:

```
wmat[wmat>0]<-5
wmat[wmat==0]<-1
wmat[wmat==5]<-0
diag(wmat)<-0
```

This gives me following matrix:

```
        A   B   C   D
1   A   0   1   0   1
2   B   1   0   0   0
3   C   0   0   0   0
4   D   1   0   0   0
```

What I struggle to do is to automatically create matrices for all the years between 1960 and 2014, do the corrections for each year and store the results into a list of matrices where I can recall each matrix by the respective year.

Any inputs are highly welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
lst <- lapply(1960:2014, function(x) {
           wmat <- distmatrix(as.Date(paste0(x, '-1-1')), 
             type="mindist", tolerance=0.5, useGW=FALSE)
           wmat[wmat>0]<-5
           wmat[wmat==0]<-1
           wmat[wmat==5]<-0
           diag(wmat)<-0
           wmat 

    }
  )
```

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks a lot akrun!

Further question: Do you know whether it is possible to make the calculation faster? I've run the code for two years, but it takes a lot of time to produce the matrices..

Comment: @jsts Glad to know that it works.  The `distmatrix` code takes most of the time.  There might be other packages which does faster calculation.  But, I am not very sure about it.